# reverse expansion order with optional parameters

Tags: macros, expansion, optional-arguments

Trying to implement a command with more than nine parameters (that also reverses things about) when there are, e.g., 8 of them, the first invocation is temporarily saved with `\def\mytemp{\mycommandtwo{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}`, and its expansion must be postponed after the second `\mycommandone` takes control: the latter has a first optional parameter.

A snippet that I supposed to gradually build arguments is:

```
\newcommand\mypriorcommand[8]{%
  \def\mytemp{\mycommandtwo{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}%
  \expandafter\mytemp\mycommandone%
}

\newcommandx\mycommandone[4][1,2,3]{%
   % #4 is mandatory
}

\newcommand\mycommandtwo[9]{%
   % #9 is one more parameter besides the eight
}
```

assuming that `\mycommandone` becomes saturated with 4 arguments, before the expansion of `\mytemp` encounters the 9th argument to `\mycommandtwo`.

Without `\expandafter`, a correct use of `\mycommandone` - still without any arguments - would do well: take as much arguments as needed. How the "\expandafter" expansion differs in this case?

This is an MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xargs}

\title{MWE}
\author{tex.stackexchange.com}

\newcommand\test[1]{\typeout{--- test/1 ---}%
  \def\temp{\typeout{--- temp/3 ---}\testa{#1}}%
  \expandafter\temp\testb%
}

\newcommand\testa[2]{\typeout{--- testa/4 ---}4=#1 5=#2}

\newcommandx\testb[3][1,2]{\typeout{--- testb/2 ---}1=#1 2=#2 3=#3}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\test{% EDIT: renamed arguments
  4th
}[1st][2nd]{%
  3rd
}{%
  5th
}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**:
It typesets `4=4th 5=1=1st 2=2nd 3=3rd 5th` and prints:

```
--- test/1 ---
--- temp/3 ---
--- testa/4 ---
--- testb/2 ---
```

whereas it should typeset `1=1st 2=2nd 3=3rd 4=4th 5=5th` and the order should be test/1, testb/2, temp/3, testa/4.

**EDIT**: Here is how building gradually arguments *without reversing arguments* works for me:

```
\newcommandx\testc[4][1,2]{2=#1 3=#2 4=#3 5=#4}
\renewcommand\test[1]{1=#1 \testc}
```

**EDIT**: Also using a variation with `\expandafter`:

```
\newcommandx\testc[4][1,2]{2=#1 3=#2 4=#3 5=#4}
\renewcommand\test[1]{1=#1 \def\temp{\relax}\expandafter\temp\testc}
```

Please a plain `TeX` solution? Thank s.

Comment: You're asking for a plain TeX or a Plain TeX solution? Sounds difficult with `\documentclass`;-)

Comment: in terms of `\def`, `newcommand[x]`, square brackets, TeX expansion macros.

Comment: why define a command with that many arguments (rather than a single comma separated list for example?)

Comment: let's just say my answer is no to "using single comma separated list to avoid square brackets and the parameter number limit"...

Comment: your question is not very clear, you say you have more than 9 arguments, but your MWE only has 5 (but has optional arguments 2 and 3) so these seem to be quite different cases??

Comment: the `\mypriorcommand` is invoked with the previous 8 args built already; i simplified to an MWE to show the `\expandafter` issue; i can edit and remove the story...

Comment: for  9 arguments you could use xparse to define a command with any number of optional arguments, but for more than 9 you need to do something else (either save a list of them somewhere) or save each one in a csname, as you can not access more than 9 by number

Comment: xparse package is loaded even without \usepackage and I could do it this way; please note the possibility that was edited to build up arguments; the "implemented" commands' syntax is rigid, actually, maybe i forgot to mention this: there are optional arguments, but only a few, and in only a couple or some combinations. does it matter if its `\def\argone{#1}` or `\def\temp{\testa{#1}}`, when the command `\testa` should be expanded after `\testb`? lots of `\expandafter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `\expandafter\temp\testb` by `\testb` in `\test` macro and add the `\temp` at the end of `\testb` macro (after `3=#3`).

Answer (score 1):

Especially if you have some optional arguments it is in general much easier to generate commands like this with [newcommand](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/newcommand). This is a python script which generates the necessary support macros. For example with 10 arguments (3 optional), it generates

```
% Prototype: MACRO test OPT[#1={}] OPT[#2={}] OPT[#3={}] #4 #5 #6 #7 #8 #9 #10
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[1][]{%
  \def\test@arg@i{#1}%
  \@ifnextchar[{\test@i}{\test@i[{}]}%
}

\def\test@i[#1]{%
  \def\test@arg@ii{#1}%
  \@ifnextchar[{\test@ii}{\test@ii[{}]}%
}

\def\test@ii[#1]#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \def\test@arg@iii{#1}%
  \def\test@arg@iv{#2}%
  \def\test@arg@v{#3}%
  \def\test@arg@vi{#4}%
  \def\test@arg@vii{#5}%
  \def\test@arg@viii{#6}%
  \def\test@arg@ix{#7}%
  \def\test@arg@x{#8}%
  % Put your code here.
  % You can refer to the arguments as \test@arg@i through \test@arg@x.
}
\makeatother
```

You call it with `./newcommand.py 'MACRO test OPT[#1={}] OPT[#2={}] OPT[#3={}] #4 #5 #6 #7 #8 #9 #10'`